Do I understand correctly "Eight guns today, numbering from the right, moving up two each drive."?
In the TV show "The Crown" there is a scene in which King George VI is going hunting with a group of men. He says to them while they're walking toward their cars with their rifles...

Eight guns today, numbering from the right, moving up two each
drive. So, if you draw one or eight, not to worry, you'll be in the thick of it soon enought.

Also while he's saying it, each man picks out a number being held by one of the servants in a leather case.
I'm not sure if I understand this sentence correctly. This is what I think this means:

I already figured out that "drive" means "drive hunt" a type of hunt that involves flushing game from hiding.

"Eight guns", is pretty simple to understand. It refers to the number of hunters taking part in the hunt on this day.

I assume that "numbering" means...


A sequence of numbers indicating order or otherwise used for identification. (Wiktionary)
...therefore the hunter that picked number 1 will be allocated the first position on the right side of the row of shooters.

"Moving up two", poses the biggest problem for me. Does "up": mean "along" here. Does this mean that after the first drive, number 1 will move to the third position and number 8 to the second?


I think someone needs to know the procedure of group hunts like this to answer, it's not a basic language issue.

Note that this activity is called shooting, not hunting, and participants use shotguns, not rifles. I know next  to nothing about it, but see this website under 'Driven shooting'. I assume that two men shared each section of ground.

@Kate Bunting Do you think it's likely that "up" means "along" in this context?

The last sentence suggests that people changed position at intervals (so 1 and 8 would not always be on the ends of the line), so it probably does mean 'along'.

I concur with Kate: this is technical talk of shooting, I guess that your interpretation is right, but I don't know. In British usage hunting is done with hounds, usually on horseback, and does not involve guns. Shooting is an entirely different activity.

They are numbered 1 to 8 from the right, so if 1 and 8 will soon be "in the thick of it" then presumably the centre of the line advances and shoots, drops back, and the next pair do the same (so they don't shoot each other). I think what you need is a description of "English drive hunt".

As noted you can't work out what is going on from the words alone. And moreover it isn't important to understanding the drama. I don't know what this means in detail. If I was watching I still wouldn't know but that's okay.  There is no English learning here, sorry.

I’m voting to close this question because this is a technical question about shooting terminology and not answerable in the context of learning English Language.

I've never hunted nor shot anything more than a paper target, but I knew several who did. Hunting is a general term for going out and trying to kill wild animals either from horseback or on foot with some weapon, rifle, shotgun, bow and arrow. From the OP's quote it sounds as if the shooting party is a men. They are randomly assigned the numbers 1 to 8. They line up by number 12345678 all facing the oncoming game driven by a team of beaters (AKA hunt servants).  cont ...

cont ... After the first drive (the first pass of the beaters) they move up 2 so the order becomes 78123456 and repeat the exercise for the next drive and so on. The reason being that the most game will probably be towards the middle of the line and thin out towards the ends. The beaters are probably trained to do this. By rotating their positions in the line, the shooters each get a turn at the best positions. For safety the line of shooters would be fairly well spread out, possibly in pairs from the quote.

First comment should read ... all men with shotguns ...

Something else to lose sleep over: Is the right side of the row  from the row's perspective or when facing the row?  I assume the row's.
